# Most efficient way to calculate the highest value based on it's instances in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reduce

Assume I have an array of objects the following:

```
const objects = [{ total: 2 }, { total: 5 }, { total: 1 }, { total: 8 },{ total: 2 },{ total: 3 },{ total: 8 },{ total: 1 },{ total: 2 }];
```

What would be the best way to calculate what is the total with most instances? it our case it would be 2 as it appears more than all the rest.

```
function findTotalWithMostInstances(arr) {
  const frequency = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const total = obj.total;
    acc[total] = (acc[total] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  let totalWithMostInstances;
  let highestFrequency = 0;

  for (const total in frequency) {
    if (frequency[total] > highestFrequency) {
      totalWithMostInstances = total;
      highestFrequency = frequency[total];
    }
  }

  return parseInt(totalWithMostInstances);
}
```

Make it more efficient.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what 'efficiency' means in this context. Shortest code perhaps? Or best performance? Cleanest algorithm?

Comment: what if you more than one?

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce with a single loop and an object with additional max and values properties.

In each iteration increment the has and check if the count is greater than `max`, then get a new array for `values` with `total` as single item and increment `max`. If `max` and count is equal, just add `total` to `values`.

Finally return only `values` property.

```js
const
    findTotalWithMostInstances = array => array
        .reduce((acc, { total }) => {
            acc[total] = (acc[total] || 0) + 1;
            if (acc.max < acc[total]) {
                acc.values = [total];
                acc.max++;
            } else if (acc.max === acc[total]) {
                acc.values.push(total);
            }
            return acc;
        }, { max: 0 })
        .values,
    objects = [{ total: 2 }, { total: 5 }, { total: 1 }, { total: 8 },{ total: 2 },{ total: 3 },{ total: 8 },{ total: 1 },{ total: 2 }];

console.log(findTotalWithMostInstances(objects));
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be more than one total that occurs the same number of times. This would give you a list sorted from most instances to least:

```js
const objects = [
  { total: 2 }, { total: 5 },
  { total: 1 }, { total: 8 },
  { total: 2 }, { total: 3 },
  { total: 8 }, { total: 1 },
  { total: 2 }
];

console.log(
  Object.entries(objects.reduce((a, { total }) =>
    (a[total] = (a[total] || 0) + 1) && a, {}))
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
);
```

**Explanation:** *Reducing* into an object working as a hash table with counters for each value of total. Using *Object.entries* to convert the object into an array of arrays. *Sorting* the array based on occurences.